# Flutter ListView.builder not updating after setState

Tags: flutter

I have a TextField, a search button, and a ListView.builder. When I tap the search button a request is made to fetch some data which is put into a list. I want the ListView to update with the data that we sent back, however that isn't happening. I believe the issue is the `setState` only work going down the tree and these two widgets are in different sub-trees. Is that correct? Maybe I need to change the structure of the widgets to make this work?

```
void _updateLocationOptions(List<Location> locations) {
  locationOptions.clear();
  locationOptions = locationOptions.toList();
  setState(() {
    locationOptions = locations;
  });
}

Column(
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
  children: [
    Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      children: [
        Expanded(
          child: TextFormField(
            key: const ValueKey("locationField"),
            
            onChanged: (String value) {
              setState(() {
                locationFieldController.text = value;
              });
            },
          ),
        ),
        IconButton(
          onPressed: () async {
            final res = await eventsRepo.fetchLocationOptions(client, locationFieldController.text);
            _updateLocationOptions(res);
            print("locationOptions: $locationOptions"); // Correct value
          },
          icon: const Icon(Icons.search),
        ),
      ],
    ),
    ListView.builder(
      shrinkWrap: true,
      itemCount: locationOptions.length,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        if (locationOptions.isEmpty) {
          return null;
        }
        return Text(locationOptions[index].name!);
      },
    ),
  ],
),
```

If I do a hot reload I can get the correct data to show on screen, but not automatically as desired.

Comment: I tried to reproduce the issue, I copied your code with some modifications because I don't have the `Location` and the repo, so the list is just `List<String>` with the elements being `DateTime` represented as strings. And even without the modification that I suggested in my answer, it already works, so I'm not sure why it doesn't work in your case. You can try the code here online: [DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=68c796edd1e271effc730b6ea00d8296)

Comment: Not sure exactly why this is a problem, but I was doing this in a bottom sheet which seems to be the issue. Thanks for helping.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly why it wasn't working. Should have mentioned in the question that the widget is inside a bottom sheet's builder function. See my new answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The widget inside a bottom sheet's builder callback won't reflect the state changes from the `State` of wherever `showBottomSheet` is being called from. You have to extract the bottom sheet widget to its own `StatefulWidget`.

For example, this code **won't work**:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class AnotherScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const AnotherScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<AnotherScreen> createState() => _AnotherScreenState();
}

class _AnotherScreenState extends State<AnotherScreen> {
  bool isActive = true;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Another Screen'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: FilledButton(
          onPressed: () {
            showModalBottomSheet(
              context: context,
              builder: (context) {

                // The widget returned here won't reflect state changes
                return Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      FilledButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          setState(() {
                            isActive = !isActive;
                          });
                        },
                        child: Text('Toggle'),
                      ),
                      Text(isActive ? 'Active' : 'Inactive'),
                    ],
                  ),
                );
              },
            );
          },
          child: Text('Show Bottom Sheet'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

But this code **works**:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class AnotherScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const AnotherScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<AnotherScreen> createState() => _AnotherScreenState();
}

class _AnotherScreenState extends State<AnotherScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Another Screen'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: FilledButton(
          onPressed: () {
            showModalBottomSheet(
              context: context,
              builder: (context) {

                // The widget is now extracted to its own StatefulWidget
                return BottomSheetWidget();
              },
            );
          },
          child: Text('Show Bottom Sheet'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class BottomSheetWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const BottomSheetWidget({super.key});

  @override
  State<BottomSheetWidget> createState() => _BottomSheetWidgetState();
}

class _BottomSheetWidgetState extends State<BottomSheetWidget> {
  bool isActive = true;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          FilledButton(
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                isActive = !isActive;
              });
            },
            child: Text('Toggle'),
          ),
          Text(isActive ? 'Active' : 'Inactive'),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```